# Unable to draw to window in firebreath plugin

Tags: visual-c++, firebreath, direct2d

Ok, I'm having some massive troubles at the moment trying to write to the window in a firebreath plugin with direct2d.

I've added the FB::AttachedEvent event, and within the handler for that I spawn off a thread that I pass the PluginWindow (cast to FB::PluginWindowWin* ) where I init direct2d graphics, and have my rendering loop.

My first main concern atm tho is that the plugin window thats passed to the handler does not seem to be correct. When i get the HWND and run GetCLientRect on it I get a size that's 60 times what the window dimensions shoulb be. in the HTML i set the width and height to 640 x 480 but the rect returns dimension of 38400 x 28800?

Am I doing something crazy wrong of have I misconfigured firebreath at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem with FireBreath; FireBreath doesn't do anything with the window except give it to you when the browser provides it.  My guess is that your Firefox is acting funny; I would think it's probably a zoom related issue (as you zoom in on a page it zooms everything on the page too).

Good luck